# How to verify a remote DSN entry?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dsn

I am creating a verification utility that check various parts of an application to ensure they are configured correctly. One of the things I need to check is that the DSN entry in a Web.config file is a functional DSN, and that the DSN is pointing to the correct SQL server and database.

Currently you can run the utility in one of two modes, local or remote. My problem occurs when I am trying to verify a remote systems DSN on my local computer. I know why it doesnt work, I don't have the same DSN on my local computer. So what I need to figure out is how to either retrieve the DSN connection information from a remote machine to which I have administrative access, or to get the remote machine to verify it for me.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

*EDIT*
So apparenty the DSN info is stored in the registry too!

```
oRegConn = new ConnectionOptions();
oRegConn.Username = username;
oRegConn.Password = password;
scope = new ManagementScope(@"//" + servername + @"/root/default", oRegConn);
registry = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);

inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
inParams["sSubKeyName"] = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources\\" + 
    dsnName;
inParams["sValueName"] = "Server";

outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);
server = outParams["sValue"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the DSN conn values are stored in the registry as plaintext, which is what I needed.

```
oRegConn = new ConnectionOptions();
oRegConn.Username = username;
oRegConn.Password = password;
scope = new ManagementScope(@"//" + servername + @"/root/default", oRegConn);
registry = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);

inParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
inParams["sSubKeyName"] = "SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources\\" + 
    dsnName;
inParams["sValueName"] = "Server";

outParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParams, null);
server = outParams["sValue"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I would say that its not really a valid check if you run it on another system (yours).  The firewall rules could be different, the driver versions might be off, and a million more things.  The first thing I would say is if this is a web application, build in a page that can run these checks, like a status page.  If this is an application that you cant do that, you can use WMI to run a remote process and gather the results.  Other than that your last option might be to do a self hosting WCF service or a windows service that you connect to for querying info.  This isnt too uncommon, and I have done it many times using WMI.

Comment: The goal of this utility would be for it to be entirely separate from the main application. Essentially it is a sanity check after an installation/upgrade to pick up bits and pieces that may have gotten dropped. So I am looking for something that doesn't have to be installed, just ran from an executable. I am currently using WMI for browsing the registry, but how would I use it to start a process on the remote machine?

Comment: Also, I understand your first point, but really it is not so much for hardware and driver settings. Mainly just the connection settings.

Comment: sorry for the late reply... try this link for starting processes remotely: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Remote_Process_using_WMI_.aspx

Comment: Also, check out this MS download for some great hints on creating WMI code: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you may want to investigate PSExec (by Sysinternals). You can run your utility on a remote machine in "local" mode, as long as you have Administrative access to that machine.

Your "DSN Verification" part would have to be a separate executable/command, which can be executed by your main utility using syntax similar to the following:

```
psexec \\REMOTE-Machine <DSN Verification Utility>.exe
```

The output can be captured within C# by redirecting stdout/stderr.

<strike>Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but wouldn't just opening a connection to remote database server let you know if your connection string/DSN is okay?</strike>

Comment: The Web.config doesnt hold a connection string, just a DSN name, user and password. So unfortunately this would not work :(

Comment: Alas, unless there is a standard executable it is probably not worth prof services time to install extra stuff to verify the installation. Ideally I want the utility to be self-contained with no dependencies.

Comment: psexec is a single/stand alone executable and does not require you to install anything on either machines.

Comment: psexec is not on a server by default. So we could not remote troubleshoot a customer's server without them downloading it.

Comment: well, in that case, I guess you're kind of stuck having to do your validation in "local" mode. Package the utility with you app and have the customers run it on their end when need to troubleshoot.